# More Like This returns nothing

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I try to use "more like this" tag from Haystack but it returns no result. In ElasticSearch [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html) I found that I need to specify some parameters to make that work, like `min_term_freq`, `max_query_terms`. Can't figure out how to specify these values in Haystack.

Comment: Do you have an example of what your "mapping" looks like?

Comment: What do you mean "mapping"? Haystack index class or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set min_term_freq to 1? this worked for me. At least started to show results!!